# Notation for Line Segment vs. Directed Line Segment

Tags: geometry, notation, vectors, euclidean-geometry

This may be nit-picky, but I noticed inconsistencies in a high school math text I was reading, and I'm curious what the world thinks.

**For the most part throughout this textbook, notation is used as such:**

The notation $\overline{AB}$ is used to refer to the line that contains both points A and B.

The notation $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is used to refer to the directed line segment that begins at A and ends at B. (I have also seen this used to refer to the *ray* that begins at A and passes through B.)

My question arises in the context of rigid transformations in the Euclidian plane:

$T_\overrightarrow{AB}(P)$ where $P$ is a figure in the plane.

This asks us to translate $P$ by the directed line segment $\overrightarrow{AB}$.

In some places in this textbook, however, this translation is written as $T_\overline{AB}(P)$.

This seems questionable: how can you translate a figure along a line without orientation or endpoints? Are we supposed to assume that the order of the letters describes the orientation? (actually, there's no question we're *supposed* to assume this...but *should we?*)

Am I being nit-picky or is this reasonable?

Comment: No, this is reasonable. The direction is necessary. Otherwise you will not be able to decide if you have to translate from $A$ to $B$ or $B$ to $A$. Please provide the title of the book, including the year of printing and edition, and the address of the publisher, so we can arrange for a flogging of the sloppy typesetter.

Comment: The notation $\overline{AB}$ is also sometimes used for vectors. So there's a very remote possibility this was left over from an earlier edition that used different notations.